# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal') cant solve

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, cucumber

I always get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal')" error when I start this test.

```
import { Given, When, Then } from '@wdio/cucumber-framework';
import { expect, $ } from '@wdio/globals'
//const { Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber');
//const { expect } = require('chai');

Given('I am on the login page', () => {
    // Открываем страницу
    browser.url('https://www.saucedemo.com/');
});

When('I click login button',async () => {
    // Кликаем на кнопку "Login" с айди "login-button"
    const loginButton = $('#login-button');
    loginButton.click();
    await browser.pause(2000);
});

Then('I should see “Epic sadface: Username is required” error message',async () => {
    // Ожидаем, что появится окно с ошибкой и указанным текстом
    const expectedText = "Epic sadface: Username is required"
    const errorMessageElement = $('.error-message-container h3[data-test="error"]')
    await errorMessageElement.waitForExist();
    const errorMessage = await errorMessageElement.getText();
    //console.log(errorMessage+ '-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-==-')
    await expect(expectedText).to.equal(errorMessage);
});
```

As you see, I`ve tried to check "error message" by console.log. It was correct, errorMessage contain right string "Epic sadface: Username is required". But why it doesnt pass?

I`ve tried to "play" with async and put some "await" in code. Also I`tried replace

```
await expect(expectedText).to.equal(errorMessage)
```

with

```
await expect(expectedText).toHaveTextContaining(errorMessage)
```

Comment: Can we see the actual error printed, and the exact value of the `errorMessage`?